# Exhibit left inverse of a function, if it exists

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

Exhibit a left inverse of $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, if it exists,
where $f(x)=\begin{cases}x,\text{ if }x\in2\mathbb{Z}\\2x-1,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$.

$\underline{\text{My observations}}$:-
The given function is not onto, since $3$ has no preimage under $f$.
The function is one-one.
I tried to find range of $f$, i.e., $f(\mathbb{Z})$. According to me,
$f(\mathbb{Z})=2\mathbb{Z}\cup(4\mathbb{Z}+1)$.
So, one possible left inverse can be defined as
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
x,\text{ if }x\in2\mathbb{Z}\\
\frac{x+1}{2},\text{ if }x\in4\mathbb{Z}+1\\
0,\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

However, answer to this question is given as
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
x,\text{ if }x\in2\mathbb{Z}\\
\frac{x+1}{2},\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

Are both answers correct ?

Comment: Yes, both are correct. In your formulation, the third case can never occur, since $f(x)$ can never be of the form $4\mathbb{Z}+3$. So you can define $g$ to be anything in this case.

Comment: @rogerl, thanks for your response. You said that, third case never occurs. But I think it does occur. If it were not, then union of 2Z and 4Z+1 would be equal to Z. 
Also, one more doubt, have I calculated the range(f) correctly ?

Comment: No, the union would not need to be $\mathbb{Z}$, since (as you correctly pointed out) $f$ is not surjective!

Comment: Thanks @rogerl, I see